# MP4Box Resolution unmatched between representation

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mpeg-dash

for one of the last stability tests i try with two representation instead the only one of before to get the adaptive bitrate streaming . 
Below my encoding command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i $name -i logo.png -c:a aac -b:a 256k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -async 1 -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=$GOP:min-keyint=$GOP:no-scenecut -bf 0 -r $FPSC -b:v 1060k -maxrate 1060k -bufsize 530k -profile:v main -t $FDUR -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10,scale=-1:478" format480.mp4

ffmpeg -y -i $name -i logo.png -c:a aac -b:a 384k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -async 1 -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=$GOP:min-keyint=$GOP:no-scenecut -bf 0 -r $FPSC -b:v 2400k -maxrate 2400k -bufsize 1200k -profile:v main -t $FDUR -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10,scale=-1:1080" format1080.mp4
```

If for the first rapresentation i use 480p ffmpeg give me this error:

width not divisible by 2 (853x480)
Error initializing output stream

If i use for first representation 478p ffmpeg run correctly all two encoding but after when i try to load these two files on MP4Box to dash them live with the following command:

```
MP4Box -dash-live 8000 -subdur 8000 -profile dashavc264:live -mpd-refresh 240.0 -time-shift 24 -min-buffer 4000 -insert-utc -no-cache -out manifest.mpd format1080.mp4#video format480.mp4#video format1080.mp4#audio format480.mp4#audio
```

the error come back into mp4box:
"files have not-proportional layout 1920 x 1080 vs 849 x 478 but sample size and aspect ratio match, assuming precision issue"

I would like to understand what i don't know about, which are the resolutions that match, i understand that some movies have atypical resolution for example 1040 or 432 but the input video for this test is correct 1920 X 1080 and i wish to compress/encode it for dash and to create another representation with 480p, could i ask where I'm wrong?
Thanks!
Massimo

Comment: i try to generate first the 1080 and then one another with the 1080p one as the input which is scaled to "scale=-2:478", but the error remain, as the rounded down width resolution: 849p

Answer (score 0):

GPAC maintainer here. For MP4Box, see this branch: https://github.com/gpac/gpac/tree/dash_relax_ar_in_as. We didn't merge it because it was not compliant.

Comment: Hi Romain, I'm a bit confused, I've already installed one of the latest versions of GPAC on osx and ubuntu from git, the issue there isn't for 360p 720p and 1080p, the unmatch arise for 480 due to negative round of the width resolution, i don't believe till now that is a MP4Box problem, i think to need some more flags on ffmpeg to be sure that there is not round.

Comment: for example i tried to force the resolution 1920 x 1080 with " scale=1920:1080 " , so if the input video is not already HD will become fine HD resolution, and then generate another representation from this first one,
But actually I'm unable to get the right resolution ad output